# Android Lg G4 correct values folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Lg G4 and Sasmung s6 has same screen res 1440*2560. I Used values-xxxhdpi. but it is not working only on LG G4. Layout is changed. Can anyone guide me what value should i used for LG G4. I tried 
i get 598.0 screen density height.Calculating like

```
final float screenHeightInDp=displayMetrics.heightPixels/displayMetrics.density;
```

i tried values-h598dp but no success.
app is working fine on other 1440*2560 res devices Note4 which used values-xxhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The only way I found to make it work is making a static method and change my layout programatically when true.

```
public static boolean isLgG4(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    boolean res = metrics.density == 4.0;
    res &= metrics.densityDpi == 640;
    res &= metrics.widthPixels == 1440;
    res &= metrics.heightPixels == 2392;
    res &= metrics.xdpi == (float) 537.882;
    res &= metrics.ydpi == (float) 537.388;
    res &= metrics.scaledDensity == 4.0;
    return res;
}
```

Not exactly the nicest way, but no other solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

try lik this
**values-sw560dp** 
Because if sw560dp is not present then it  will use xxxhdpi after scaling. 
With Nexus 6, also has same resolution, this problem occured but sw560dp fixed issue for me.

Shared this, may be it will help you out.